# Spacy find text before specified word

Tags: python, regex, nlp, spacy

I'm working on the sentence `Hall is a Tony Award winner and Grammy nominee` and would like to extract the awards won (`Tony Award`), using spaCy Rule-Matcher, but I can't seem to be able to tell spaCy to look for words that come before `winner`. Is that possible? If so how could one go about it?

```
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

awards_lexical = [
            {'TEXT': {'REGEX': '\s*'}, 'OP': '*'},
            {'IS_PUNCT': True, 'OP': '*'},
            {'TEXT': {'REGEX': '^(winner|recipient)$'}},
            {'OP': '+'},
            ]
def matching(doc, pattern):
    result = []
    for sent in doc.sents:
        matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab) 
        matcher.add("matching", None, pattern)  

        matches = matcher(nlp(str(sent))) 
        if len(matches)>0:
            match = matches[-1]
            span = sent[match[1]:match[2]] 
            result.append(span.text)

    return result

csv_reader = csv.reader(open('Matheus_Schmitz_hw02_bios.csv', encoding='utf-8'))
limit = 500
count = 0

open("hw2_lexical.jl", "w").close()
with open('hw2_lexical.jl', 'w') as hw2_lexical:
    for (idx, (url, bio)) in tqdm(enumerate(csv_reader), total=limit):
        count += 1
        result = {}
        result['url'] = url
        result['awards'] = matching(nlp(bio), awards_lexical)        
        hw2_lexical.write(str(result)+'\n')
        if count>=limit:
            break
        pass
    hw2_lexical.close()
print(count)
```

From my code, I'd think that spaCy would include any text before the chosen word, but all variations I've are only giving me the text from winner|won|awarded onwards, not the text before, which is where the prize name most often is.

Comment: Your code is not clear, can you please create an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What is `matching`? Also, if you want to match something before `winner`, why don't you even use `winner` in the pattern you are using? Note `won|awarded|award-winning` seem to go *before* the awards name, don't they?

Comment: Also, do you want to "add" the `winner` condition to the existing `awards_lexical` rule or do you consider adding another pattern here? What is the `winner` pattern? How can you define it (in order to extract)?

Comment: I'd define the winner pattern as one or more capitalized words followed by winner or recipient. This alrady gives me some hint as I was not consdering filtering by capitalized words!

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to reply, but yes it did! After adapting in my full code that worked quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea seems valid, you may extract one or more capitalized words followed with `winner` or `recipient` using

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

text= "Hall is a Tony Award winner and Grammy nominee"
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("Winner", None, [{'POS': 'PROPN', 'OP':'+'}, {'TEXT': {'REGEX': '(?i)^(?:winner|recipient)$'}}])
doc = nlp(text)
matches = matcher(doc)
spans = [doc[start:end] for _, start, end in matches]
for span in spacy.util.filter_spans(spans):
    print(span.text)
# => Tony Award winner
```

The `(?i)^(?:winner|recipient)$` regex used as the right-hand token in the pattern matches a whole `winner` or `recipient` token in a case insensitive way.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly once adapted in my code :)